# Swift how to unit test a function with dependencies

Tags: swift, unit-testing, mocking, stubbing

Hi I am new to mocking and stubbing as these are concepts I have heard about but haven't actually seen an example that explains how this works. I understand basic unit testing but I haven't found a place where I get an explanation with a simple example on mocks and stubs.

In my application I have these two functions which I would like to test but I do not know how to go about it since there is a dependency.

```
private func setOverviewValues(weeklyData: CDPRewards, formattedTotal: String, displayMode: PointsDescriptionMode) {
    let monthYearString = createSubtitle(from: displayMode, with: weeklyData)
    view.setOverAllPoints(topValue: formattedTotal, bottomValue: monthYearString)
}
```

and

```
 private func createSubtitle(from displayMode: PointsDescriptionMode, with weeklyData: CDPRewards) -> String {

    switch displayMode {
    case .weeklyPoints:
        if let monthString = weeklyData.month,
            let yearString = weeklyData.year {
            return displayMode.rawValue + monthString + " " + yearString
        }
        return PointsDescriptionMode.weeklyPoints.rawValue
    default:
        return displayMode.rawValue
    }
}
```

I would like help to show me how I can achieve testing of these functions or just a simple example that demonstrates mocking and stubbing. It would also be great to be pointed in the right direction in terms of books or blogs I can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the short answer.

I don't Unit Test `private` functions / methods, but just public API. In fact, here you are not interested in the internals of a component but just to its behavior from the outside world.

This is the long answer.

In your particular case, I would just Unit Test the second function. Why? Because the first one contains a side effect. You are going to modify something on a view. And views are difficult to test using Unit Tests. For views I would use acceptance tests (e.g. User Interface Testing).

Returning to the test for the second function I would use a *Value Based Unit Test*.

So, giving specific inputs you should expect the right output. Also edge cases should be tested.

Here some useful links on the subject:

- https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/a-complete-list-of-articles-on-unit-testing-with-swift-from-2017-9be8f046ef25
- https://qualitycoding.org/

Here a book I recommend to read (it's not Swift but Java based):

- Growing Object-Oriented Software, Guided by Tests